# Close application without .net framework's error prompt window

Tags: c#, winforms

Codes handles unhandled exceptions as below in my project.

```
   static void FnUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs _UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
        {
            Exception _Exception = (Exception)_UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject;
            OnUnwantedCloseSendEmail(_Exception.Message);
        }
```

I am using **OnUnwantedCloseSendEmail** method for sending email for error reports. Last line of OnUnwantedCloseSendEmail method is **Application.Restart();**

When this approach correctly works, .net framework show an prompt window for error as below and application not close and restart until press the quit button.

[image]

How can i exit application without this prompt and **how can i apply this approach when application frozen too.**

Comment: Is this a ClickOnce-deployed application? Does it support commandline arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157905%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Calling this with the `UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException` parameter will prevent Winform to route exceptions down to the `Application.ThreadException` event and thus this dialog won't ever show up.

You can also alter the app.config file to get the same result:

```
<configuration>
  <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"/>
</configuration>
```

Personnaly I prefer the hard-coded route.

Just so we're clear: **this will only get rid of the dialog**, not solve the actual assembly loading or app freezing problem. :)

Comment: You also could add your own event handler to Application.ThreadException. If I recall correctly Winform will stop showing the error dialog as soon as there's a single handler registered for this event. But frankly I think the above solution works better.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to catch everything with this

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        // let IDE to handle exceptions
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            Run();
        else
            try
            {
                Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
                Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
                Run();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // catch exceptions outside of Application.Run
                UnhandledException(e);
            }
    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // catch non-ui exceptions
        UnhandledException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    }

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // catch ui exceptions
        UnhandledException(e.Exception);
    }

    private static void UnhandledException(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            // here we restart app
        }
        catch
        {
            // if we are here - things are really really bad
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would advise against this. If the application is meant to crash and restart then there's no need to route exceptions down to ThreadException event.

Comment: @Crono1981, and the reason for this is ...? Do you need error logs or OP screenshot from the customer altogether with the most informative message ever *software doesn't works*?

Comment: It hardly matters whether it is necessary to inform the end user or not: Application.ThreadException can only catch exceptions in the UI thread while Domain.UnhandledException can catch EVERY exceptions thrown in any thread in the same domain. So there's no point handling both events IMHO. Especially if both only calls another method anyway.

Comment: @Crono1981, so it does the job, right? Catching *everything*? Though I see the point now, thanks.

Comment: @Sinatr Where should I add this approach? Program.cs?

Comment: @Sinatr it is one way to do it, yes, but quite frankly I believe it is not the right way.

Comment: @Kerberos any calls to Application.SetUnhandledMode must be done before any windows ever shows up. So yes it's likely that you'll want this in Program.cs.

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you i will modify my codes according to this approach soon. So is this approach appropriate for application freeze?

Comment: @Kerberos no it won't, but then again nothing (*efficiently*) will. Application freezing is something you must solve with proper threading strategies and resources handling, not fallback methods.